# PHP function to Javascript: scan string and add words in array

Tags: php, javascript, regex, preg-match-all

Im trying to convert this php function to javascript:

```
function sanitize_words($string,$limit=false) {
    preg_match_all("/\p{L}[\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Pd}'\x{2019}]{1,}/u",$string,$matches,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    return $matches[0];
}
```

Basically, it takes this string:

```
$string = "Why hello, how are you?"
$array = sanitize_words($string);
```

And converts it into an array:

```
$array[0] = 'Why';
$array[1] = 'hello';
$array[2] = 'how';
$array[3] = 'are';
$array[4] = 'you';
```

It works great on php, but i have no idea on how to implement it on javascript, since there is no preg_match_all in [phpjs.org](http://phpjs.org). Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`String.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method, with the `g` (global) flag set on the RegEx. `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. If you *really* want to mimic your current pattern, use [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) as a reference to convert the character properties in a JavaScript pattern.

```
function sanitize_words($string) {
    return $string.match(/\w+/g);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript `split()` function will make an array from any string using a delimiter. In this case, a *space*.

```
var str = "Why hello, how are you?".split(" ")
alert(str[0]) // = "Why"
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regex, split will do in javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myString = "zero one two three four";

var mySplitResult = myString.split(" ");

for(i = 0; i < mySplitResult.length; i++){
    document.write("<br /> Element " + i + " = " + mySplitResult[i]); 
}
</script>
```

Displays:

```
Element 0 = zero
Element 1 = one
Element 2 = two
Element 3 = three
Element 4 = four
```

As a side note, in your PHP script, if all you are wanting to do is create an array of words you should use `explode()` it has a LOT less overhead:

```
<?php
$pizza  = "piece1 piece2 piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";
// to remove non alpha-numeric chars, and still less costly
$pizza = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/', '', $pizza);
$pieces = explode(" ", $pizza);
echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
echo $pieces[1]; // piece2
?>
```

Comment: well, the regex gets rid of commas, exclamation marks, etc. still the split works kind of nice for my needs.